# Selenium as a service on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: java, bash, selenium, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to run selenium(headless) as a service on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

case "${1:-''}" in
'start')
    if test -f /tmp/selenium.pid
    then
        echo "Selenium is already running."
    else
        export DISPLAY=localhost:99.0
        java -jar /opt/selenium-server-standalone-3.3.1.jar -port 4444 > /var/log/selenium/output.log 2> /var/log/selenium/error.log & echo $! > /tmp/selenium.pid
        echo "Starting Selenium..."

        error=$?
        if test $error -gt 0
        then
            echo "${bon}Error $error! Couldn't start Selenium!${boff}"
        fi
    fi
;;
'stop')
    if test -f /tmp/selenium.pid
    then
        echo "Stopping Selenium..."
        PID=`cat /tmp/selenium.pid`
        kill -3 $PID
        if kill -9 $PID ;
            then
                sleep 2
                test -f /tmp/selenium.pid && rm -f /tmp/selenium.pid
            else
                echo "Selenium could not be stopped..."
            fi
    else
        echo "Selenium is not running."
    fi
    ;;
'restart')
    if test -f /tmp/selenium.pid
    then
        kill -HUP `cat /tmp/selenium.pid`
        test -f /tmp/selenium.pid && rm -f /tmp/selenium.pid
        sleep 1
        export DISPLAY=localhost:99.0
        java -jar /opt/selenium-server-standalone-3.3.1.jar -port 4444 > /var/log/selenium/output.log 2> /var/log/selenium/error.log & echo $! > /tmp/selenium.pid
        echo "Reload Selenium..."
    else
        echo "Selenium isn't running..."
    fi
    ;;
*)      # no parameter specified
    echo "Usage: $SELF start|stop|restart"
    exit 1
;;
```

esac

My virtual screen starts as on reboot through the following crontab entry

@reboot sh -c 'Xvfb :99 -ac -screen 0 1024x768x8 > /tmp/xvfb.log 2>&1 &'

I get an error above because it seems like selenium is not running headless.

If I use the code below to start selenium manually, it works as expected.

DISPLAY=:1 xvfb-run java -jar /opt/selenium-server-standalone-3.3.1.jar

How would I run the above command on start-up to set-up the selenium listender?

Comment: What is the error that you are trying to resolve?

Comment: The service times out, I'm assuming its waiting for browser to start which will never happen. Its like the virtual driver which is started by the cron is not picked up